# $[0,1]$ can not be expressed as the countably infinite union of disjoint closed subsets

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I came across the following problem and also found many discussions on MSE on this. But my proof seems to be a bit different. Please check if my proof is correct. 
**Problem:** Prove that $[0,1]$ can not be written as the countably infinite union of disjoint closed intervals.
**My solution:** Suppose $[0,1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$. Let $[a_1,b_1]$ be the interval containing $0$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ be the interval containing $1$.
Consider a point $x_1\in [b_1,a_2]$.
Suppose $x\in [a_3,b_3]$. Now take $x_4\in [b_1,a_3]$ and $x_5\in [b_3,a_2]$. This way we can find a set $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ where each $x_n$ will be contained in a distinct closed interval. We claim that $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is uncountble. Starting at $x_1$, we can decide to go to left of $x_1$ or right of $x_1$. If we go left, we find the point $x_4$; if we go right, we find the point $x_5$. Continuing, we can construct as sequence of $L$ and $R$'s to construct a new point $x_n$. But we know that the number of $L,R$ sequences is uncountable.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what $[a_3,b_3]$ is. Also, if you can enumerate a set as $\{ x_n \}_{n \ge 1}$, isn't that set countable, by definition?

Comment: @legionwhale you are right. I should find a better way to write the set of points $x_i$'s.

Comment: Your argument only uses finite sequences of $L$'s and $R$'s, and the set of such finite sequences is countable. It's true that the set of infinite $L,R$ sequences is uncountable, but as currently worded your argument makes no use of any infinite $L,R$ sequence.

Comment: @LeeMosher you are right. I was basically trying to mimic the proof of the fact that the Cantor set is uncoutable. I am unsure whether an infinite string of $L,R$ even encodes an address of some $x_i$(again $x_i$ is a bad notation as it already enumerates the set).

Comment: A closed set need not be an interval. You have shown only that $[0,1]$ is not a countable union of pairwise-disjoint closed intervals. I cannot recall the reference for the main result. It is an old classic, and I expect it is not easy.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes I am aware of the "closed set" version of this problem. But as of now I am trying to solve the "closed interval" version only(which I believe to be simpler than the closed set version).